# Java Collections Sorting Hypothetical

Tags: java, sorting

I am currently a computer science major and am taking a course in advanced java programming. My question today is if you have two identical lists, lets call them list1 and list2, and you invoke Collections.sort(list1) and Collections.sort(list2), is it possible for these two lists to be different after invoking this? My textbook says that it is possible, while my professor says it isn't. Can someone please clarify this for me?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "different".

Comment: I would hope it's not.  Is there some nuance mentioned in the book that isn't in the question?

Answer (score 4):

If we consider the obvious case such as sorting `List<Integer>`, then no it's not possible. If you're sorting two identical lists, they should be properly sorted of course.

However since `Collections.sort()` requires that the objects being sorted are `Comparable`, you can always implement `Comparable` poorly. For example you could have `compareTo()` return a random value (or the time of day, or anything not related to the object actually being sorted), and you wouldn't have any idea how they would be sorted.

`Collections.sort()` can notice if `compareTo()` is implemented wrong and will throw an exception saying `Comparison method violates its general contract!`. However it's not 100% guaranteed to notice this, so **technically** it is possible to have 2 identical collections sorted in different ways.

As equality is defined by `Object.equals()`, but comparison is defined by `Comparable.compareTo()` or `Comparator.compare()`, like the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) says:

> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural
>   orderings be consistent with equals.

Otherwise it is possible that equal elements are sorted differently.

Comment: also having equal different objects (2 identical objects each one with different memory allocation) can cause a "different" order from memory p.o.v but not from object content comparison, again depends on compareTo() implementation

Comment: For instance, if `compareTo()` relies on a default `toString()` method that is not overridden by the class of your list elements, you may end up comparing the internal address of the objects via the default `hashCode()` method.

Comment: An example of implementing `Comparable` poorly is to involve *any* kind of random value.  That's the only physical way I could see sorting two identical lists and getting different results.